# Scroll on top of content, visible on mouse over jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrollbar

It's XXI century and all I could find on that is messy js/jquery libraries with huge footprint in your code ... I want to achieve this:

[Scrollable div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0ffq.png)

Is there a jQuery library that let's me do this without writing my whole page around it?

It's just a div with lots of identical DIVs inside of it.

Maybe hiding the scroll and imitating it with something else? My last resort would be hiding the scroll and just retaining the scroll function if that is also possible.

EDIT: Wow. Wasn't expecting negative votes for a question... Anyway.

The image I've posted is from my Designer, I am trying to replicate it while coding the design.

The current code is basically this:

```
<div class='container'>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
<div class='item'></div>
</div>
```

And so on until it starts overflowing. It's just a block DIV elements within a DIV that has overflow: auto; on it.

Comment: Its XXI century and people talking so much about messy footprints and trying nothing to solve their problem rather posting an image as reference and expecting others to do a lot.

Comment: I've tried over 50 jQuery scrollbars and maybe that many of solutions found here so I decided to ask you guys. Really sorry if that offends you.

Comment: Can you add some code please? Thanks!

Comment: Added some code but it really is just this for now with some font styling.

Answer (score 0):

If you want replace scroll bar with custom scroll bar you can use [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) ([demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html)) or [slimScroll](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll)([demo](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll))